# Is volatile always necessary when a variable is accessed by multiple threads (with only one thread writing)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

It is commonly recommended to use **volatile** for a variable that is written by only one thread and can be read by another thread at any time. The reasons to use **volatile** or synchronization method could be

- The compiler might rearrange the order of the statements
- The compiler may load a variable to register at its first use, then reuse, for as long as possible
- and the processor could rearrange the order of memory access instructions

However, I still uncertain about whether to use **volatile** in some cases. Consider the following example: we defined a ordinary variable `completed`, start with `0`; There is a child thread will read it after 5ms and the main thread will update the value first.

```
int completed;

void readFlag() {
    System.out.println("Read completed value: " + completed);
}

public void testViolatile() {
    var executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executor.schedule(this::readFlag, 5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    completed = 1;  # update will happen before the read

    // cleanup
    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
    }
}
```

I think the child thread can read the final value of `completed`, that is **1**, **volatile** is not necessary here, did I make a mistake?  Would any compiler or processor optimizations potentially disrupt the result?

Comment: While confusing, I found thinking in terms of read and write barriers to be helpful. Until a read barrier is emitted, you have no guarantee for reader visibility, or a write barrier on if its state has been committed. The visibility is per-thread and not global. You could read about why double checking locking used to be broken in Java for a nice explanation of failure modes. There are quirks like the cache coherency model, Java's memory model, compiler, etc. that can allow things to seem correct but not be guaranteed. Thankfully an unnecessary barrier is cheap and may be optimized away.

Answer (score 1):

> `completed = 1;  # update will happen before the read`

That comment is incorrect. The main thread is very likely to assign `completed=1` before the worker thread accesses `completed`, but nothing in the program *guarantees* that the events will happen in that order. It is possible that the main thread could be preempted in between submitting the task to the `executor` and assigning to `completed`, and the worker thread could read `completed` during that interval.

> I think the child thread can read the final value of completed, that is 1, volatile is not necessary here

That also is wrong. Even if, in *real* time, the main thread actually does assign `completed` before the worker thread calls `readFlag`, there is no *guarantee* that `readFlag` will see the changed value. You've done nothing to establish a "happens before" relationship between the events in the two different threads.

> Is volatile always necessary when...?

Actually, `volatile` is *never* necessary in a Java program. `volatile` is a short-cut. Anything that you can do with `volatile` can also be done by other means.

My *personal* opinion is that `volatile` is an advanced topic. Beginners should avoid it until they have a full understanding of what "happens before" means in Java.

---

**Update**

> So in the above case, we should use a synchronization(volatile, lock..) to make sure the visibility or proper sequencing?

One way to achieve both predictable visibility and predictable sequencing would be to use a `Semaphore`:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

Semaphore sem;
int completed;

void readFlag() {
    doSomeOtherStuffInWorker(...);
    sem.acquire();
    System.out.println("Read completed value: " + completed);
}

public void testViolatile() {
    sem = new Semaphore(0);
    var executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executor.schedule(this::readFlag, 5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    doSomeOtherStuffInMain(...);
    completed = 1;
    sem.release();

    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
    }
}
```

`Semaphore` provides one way for a single thread to tell some other single thread, "I'm done!" or "I'm ready!" or ...

The `acquire()` call in the worker thread waits for the `release()` call in the main thread. That ensures that the worker will not try to look at `completed` until after (in real-time) the main thread has set `completed`, and it also "synchronizes" the threads. That is to say, it ensures that whatever "happens before" the `release()` in the main thread must also "happen before" the `acquire()` in the worker.

But notice! I added the `doSomeOtherStuff...` calls to emphasize that there's no point in even having multiple threads if *everything* they do is synchronized. The whole point of using more than one thread is to let them work independently of each other. Of course, they have to sync up *sometimes,* but the more time they can spend working independently, the more benefit you get from having them at all.

Comment: So in the above case, we should use a synchronization(volatile, lock..) to make sure the visibility or proper sequencing? A more applicable case is creating/updating an object, and submit a task(which reads the object) to thread pool for background processing. Should we also need to use synchronization method to ensure the worker thread (in pool) can see the updated object?

Comment: @JackyWang, see the "update" in my answer (above).